Why is the Einstein Field Equation relevant in the area theorem?
I am studying Area theorem and the first assumption is as follows :

If Einstein equation holds satisfy null energy condition...

I don't understand in general, what does it mean to satisfy Einstein equation ? I mean to solve EFE, we just need a metric tensor. Does this assumption in Area theorem suggest that we are only taking those metric tensors that fit EFE but I guess all metric tensors satisfy EFE.
Please explain the above assumption.

Write down a "random" metric tensor and plug it into EFE. I'll be shocked if you get 0.

@ConnorBehan OP is correct that you can always satisfy the EFE as long as you pick the correct stress tensor

Of course, easily and quickly determining which metrics correspond to which stress-energy-momentum tensors without simplifying assumptions is an unsolvable problem due to the EFE’s great nonlinearity…

@NíckolasAlves “you can always satisfy the EFE as long as you pick the correct stress tensor” - This is not self evident. Can you prove that no metric exists that is not a solution? The opposite does seem evident at least physically. If we take any physical SET and physical boundary conditions, they would necessarily result in some specific spacetime. But not vice versa.

@safesphere Choose a metric. Compute the Einstein tensor. Define the stress tensor to be $T_{ab} = \frac{1}{8\pi G} G_{ab}$. The Einstein equations are satisfied by construction. The key challenge here (which you pointed out explicitly and I hid in "as long as you pick the correct...") is that this stress tensor may not be obtainable from existing forms of matter. This trick, however, is the standard procedure to find metrics with warp drives, wormholes, and etc, and then one checks whether the matter content is physical a posteriori

@NíckolasAlves So what you are saying is that finding the SET explicitly is trivial just by differentiating any given metric, but the opposite is not given. If we take a specific SET and boundary conditions, then finding the metric involves solving differential equations that may not have a solution. And yet physically it is fairly obvious that any (at least smooth) SET would produce a spacetime. Good point.

@NíckolasAlves In physics, solving a differential equation means solving an initial value problem. One has to find a unique function that satisfies both the equation and the boundary conditions.  If you take any metric and calculate the energy-stress tensor, then although you have found a function that satisfies the EFE equation, it may not satisfy the imposed boundary conditions.

Where is that quote from? Are you sure it said that the equations need to satisfy the null condition?

@JanG You can always cook up the boundary conditions you need, just like I cooked up the stress tensor itself. The point is that the EFE only have physical meaning when the stress tensor is sufficiently constrained by extra conditions

@NíckolasAlves You probably mean the energy conditions. As I see it, it is the physicality of the boundary conditions, not the energy conditions, that is determinative. And these are given a priori.

@JanG The energy conditions are also determinative (in the sense that a solution made up of an impossible stress tensor is not physical). The Alcubierre warp drive is unphysical because there is not enough negative energy available to build it. I guess the Taub-NUT solution is an example of an unphysical geometry due to the choice of unphysical initial conditions

You actually should not break this sentence in smaller bits. The relevant hypothesis is

If Einstein equation is satisfied and the null energy condition holds

The theorem needs this specific assumption because what is really relevant is that the null convergence condition ($R_{ab}k^a k^b \geq 0$ for all null $k^a$) holds. The NCC holds whenever both the Einstein equations and the null energy condition hold. Hence, the role of the EFE here is to restate a condition on curvature (the null convergence condition) to a condition on the matter content (the null energy condition).
The point is thus that the stress tensor required for your metric to be a solution for the EFE has to satisfy the null energy condition. This is the case for all known forms of classical matter, but this condition is easily violated in quantum theory (which is the reason the area of evaporating black holes can decrease once quantum effects are taken into account).
These sorts of hypotheses are very common in black hole thermodynamics and related topics. You often need a condition on the Ricci tensor to prove a certain result. While the condition on the Ricci tensor is usually hard to interpret in terms of the matter content of the universe, you can convert the condition to a condition on the stress tensor if you assume the validity of the Einstein equations. However, if the condition for the stress tensor holds and the Einstein equations do not, the result may no longer be true (because the condition on the Ricci tensor may not hold).

Why condition on Ricci tensor is usually hard to interpret in terms of matter content of universe ????

when you say "the condition is easily violated in quantum theory", is it because energy momentum tensor could be negative in quantum physics ??

@TalhaAhmed The Ricci tensor is a geometrical quantity. Before you impose the Einstein equations, it has nothing to do with matter

@TalhaAhmed Yes, you can have negative energy densities in quantum field theory. A common example is the Casimir effect

Thank you so much for all of your explanation. Just one last thing... in the last line you said "if the condition for stress tensor holds and Einstein equations do not hold...." can you give me some example related to it like when it could happen ?

@TalhaAhmed It would need to involve some modified theory of gravity in which the EFE do not hold. Basically, at the end of the day you need a condition on the Ricci tensor. If your assumptions give only a condition on the stress tensor, but not on the Ricci tensor, that doesn't take you very far
